# Why is the value of the second number 14 more than the first number?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I run a C program in a 32-bit machine with `gcc 7.5.0`.

Why is the value of the second number 14 more than the first number?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a[5];
    printf("%p\n", &a);
    printf("%p\n", &a+1);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
0x7ffd7293f560
0x7ffd7293f574
```

Why the second number is 14 more than the first number?

Comment: the difference is `20`: `0x...74 - 0x...60 = 0x00..0014 = 16 + 4 = 20`.

Answer (score 6):

The object `a` is declared as:

```
int a[5];
```

and has a size equal to `20` (according to the output).

So the expression `&a+1` uses pointer arithmetic that increases the value of the pointer `&a` by the size of the object `a`. Since `14` hexadecimal value is `20`, that is of the size of the object `a`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[5];

    printf( "sizeof( a ) = (in decimal)%zu and (in hex)%zx\n", 
            sizeof( a ), sizeof( a ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
sizeof( a ) = (in decimal)20 and (in hex)14
```

Here is a simplified example of the pointer arithmetic.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    printf( "%p => %d\n", ( void * )&a[0], a[0] );
    printf( "%p => %d\n", ( void * )( &a[0] + 1 ), *( &a[0] + 1 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
0x7ffe2bfb4840 => 1
0x7ffe2bfb4844 => 2
```

As you can see the difference between the value of the addresses is equal to 4 that is the value of the expression `sizeof( int )`. In your program in the question there is used an object of the type `int[5]` that has the size `20` ( `5 * sizeof( int )` ).

Answer (score 4):

> Why the second number is 14 more than the first number?

It is 20(dec) because the size of `int a[5]` is 20 (4*5) (assuming the size of 
 `int` is 4 on your platform), so `&a+1` would increase 20 (= 14 in hexadecimal).

Are you trying to do this?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {
     int a[5];
     printf("%p\n", a);
     printf("%p\n", a+1);
     return 0;
 }
```

Output:

```
0060FEEC
0060FEF0

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.088 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Difference is

```
0060FEF0-0060FEEC=4
```